# How can I use jquery to move text from multiple elements in order?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to move text from multiple elements to other elements in order. I don't want to move the element, just the inner text. The setup is basically:

```
<p class='button_text'>Text here.</p>
<p class='button_text'>More text here.</p>
```

`

```
<div class="button">Button 1</div> <div class="button">Button 2</div>
```

Which I tried to change with:

```
var button_text = $('.button_text').html();
$('.button').html(button_text);
```

which produces

```
<div class="button">Text here.</div>
<div class="button">Text here.</div>
```

But I want it to produce:

```
<div class="button">Text here.</div>
<div class="button">More text here.</div>
```

Help much appreciated!

Comment: What is button_text?

Comment: My bad--updated correctly now.

Comment: First it's semantic HTML error to declare two html element with the same id , use class instead !

Comment: Okay, I updated that. But it's not really relevant to main question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try looping through the p tags first. like -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var btn = $('.button_text');
            var index = 0;
            $('.button').each(function(){
                $(this).html($(btn[index]).text());
                index++;
            });
    });
```